# ASP.NET Core 7 + EF Core 7 Change JSON schema

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, schema

I'm developing application to generate test data.

I don't know how it's called, but I need to change JSON schema from:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "data": "Daniel",
    "typeID": 1,
    "type": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Name",
        "templates": []
    }
}
```

to:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "data": "Daniel",
    "typeID": 1,
    "type": "Name"
}
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpGet("{data}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetOne(string data)
{
    Template template =_templateService.GetOne(data);

    if (template == null)
        return await Task.FromResult(NotFound($"Not Found: {data}"));

    return await Task.FromResult(Ok(template));
}
```

Entities:

```
public sealed class Type
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public List<Template> Templates { get; set; } = new(); 
}

public sealed class Template
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? Data { get; set; }
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public Type? Type { get; set; }
}
```

And I am using `Newtonsoft.Json`.

I tried using `[JsonIngore]` near

```
public List<Template> Templates { get; set; } = new();
```

but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `JsonIgnore` attribute is used when you want to exclude the property/field to be serialized/deserialized. From your input and expected data, you should create another class and convert the input data to class for expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use JsonIgnore is a good idea, but you you will have to add a string property that you want instead

```
using System.Text.Json;

public sealed class Template
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? Data { get; set; }
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    public Type? Type { get; set; }
    
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public string TypeName { get {return Type.Name;}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the purpose of the `JsonIgnore` attribute as mentioned in the comment. From your question and expected result, you need a type casting from the input data to the expected result.

1. Create a class for the expected result. Implement the [implicit conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) to convert a `Template` instance to a `TemplateOutputModel` instance.

```cs
public class TemplateOutputModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? Data { get; set; }
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    
    public static implicit operator TemplateOutputModel(Template template)
    {
        return new TemplateOutputModel
        {
            ID = template.ID,
            Data = template.Data,
            TypeID = template.TypeID,
            Type = template.Type.Name
        };
    }
}
```

2. Cast the `Template` instance to the `TemplateOutputModel` instance.

```cs
[HttpGet("{data}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetOne(string data)
{
    Template template = _templateService.GetOne(data);

    if (template == null)
        return await Task.FromResult(NotFound($"Not Found: {data}"));

    return await Task.FromResult(Ok((TemplateOutputModel)template));
}
```